# setCustomValidity not displaying message using onchange mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am not able to see any messages for `setCustomValidity`. I want to get bubble messages on change. I can see the `bordercolor` red but nothing for `setCustomValidity`.

JavaScript code:

```
function CityValidate(input) {
    var reg = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+$");
    if (!reg.test(input.value)) {
        input.setCustomValidity("City Name should have letters");
        input.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="city" value="" size="40" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" placeholder="City" required title="Only characters allowed" onchange="CityValidate(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `setCustomValidity` you have to then use `reportValidity`:

```
e.setCustomValidity('Your message here.');
e.reportValidity();
```